# Non-blocking way to check if there is data on a iofstream

Tags: c++, file, nonblocking, ostream

I need to have a way to check if there is data to read on a file (fifo) in a non-blocking way.
I have tried using [peek](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/); but it is blocking, I have tried to [get](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) and then [unget](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/unget/) a character in order to check the file without altering the contents; but once again `get` is blocking...

The only non-blocking solution I have found is to use `std::getline(file, line_str)` and check if the string is empty; however this does **not** suit my needs as it alters the data on the file. (The data is a serialized object I will read once I detect there is something to read).

Note: I need this to be non-blocking: I have multiple file streams and need to check all of them regularly to see if there is an object to read/deserialize.

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to achieve:

**Sender.cpp**:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
extern "C"{
    #include <sys/stat.h>      // S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR, mkfifo
}
#include <cerrno>              // errno

int main(int, char** argv) {
    std::string pipe = "foobar";
    if(mkfifo(pipe.c_str(), S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) < 0){
        if (errno != EEXIST){
            std::cerr << errno;
        }
    }
    std::ofstream file{pipe.c_str()};
    file.write("boop", 4); // Simulated object serialization

}
```

**Reader.cpp**:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
extern "C"{
    #include <sys/stat.h>      // S_IRUSR, S_IWUSR, mkfifo
}
#include <cerrno>              // errno

int main(int, char** argv) {
    std::string pipe = "foobar";
    if(mkfifo(pipe.c_str(), S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) < 0){
        if (errno != EEXIST){
            std::cerr << errno;
        }
    }
    std::ifstream file{pipe.c_str()};
    // ...
    /* Do check for data and read/deserialize if any data */
    // This is in some sort of loop that goes over the different
    // filestreams and checks to see if they have data to treat
}
```

Any help is really appreciated...

EDIT:
Following Zoso's answer I tried using the file size to determine if the file had been changed; however attempeting to get the size of a fifo named pipe is not possible :  `filesystem error: cannot get file size: Operation not supported [myFilePath]`

Comment: Non-blocking I/O isn't straightforward with C++ streams. You can use `select`/`poll` if you can retrieve the file descriptor(s). That involves some hacks. Alternatively, you could directly use POSIX I/O which would allow you to `select`/`poll`.

Comment: If you can get the FD you can use `ioctl(...FIONREAD)`.

Comment: @P.P +1 for poll and C, but unfortunately I'l using boost for the serialization and working with file descriptors is a little bit of a pain...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would work for your particular use case but you could use the `filesystem` APIs. A simple example is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    while (true) {
        auto path = fs::current_path().append("test");
        std::cout <<"Press enter to know file size of "<<path.c_str() <<'\n';
        char c= getchar();
        try {
            std::cout<<"Size of "<<path.c_str()<<"is "<<fs::file_size(path)<<'\n';
        } catch(fs::filesystem_error& e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
        }        
    }
}
```

As and when the file gets data, that can be kept track of based on the increasing `size` and the data to be processed can be tracked as and when that data is consumed.

Comment: I like the size hack ! I'll try it out asap